# User Directory without a Plugin

Tags: login

*GOAL:* Develop a password-protected user directory without a membership plugin. The login credentials are the same for everyone.

*QUESTION:* Will this strategy keep the info private, or am I missing something?

1. Create a custom post type with options:

   ```
   'public' => true,
   'has_archive' => false,
   'exclude_from_search' => true,
   'publicly_queryable'  => false,
   ```
2. create a password-protected page with a custom page template, displaying the custom post type query (the list of addresses).
3. add a password form to the custom page template, like so:

   ```
   global $post;
   get_header();
   if ( ! post_password_required( $post ) ) {
       // …
   } else {
       echo get_the_password_form(); 
   }
   ```

Additional Notes:

- Custom Post Type paired with Advanced Custom Fields will set up fields for address, phone numbers, names, etc.
- An editor (or two) will keep the directory up to date

Comment: "what do you think" is an invitation for a discussion which is not how the site works. Personally I do not even know what does HOA means. The question probably needs rewriting and focusing on asking one question at a time or at lest research and present the alternatives

Comment: edited to make simpler. sorry about that.

Comment: Please save yourself a TON of hassle in the future and DO NOT use a single username/password for everyone to use.  This is not secure and it is a huge pain in the admin's rear end if any single person needs to be removed from access. You'd need to set new credentials and send to everyone.  Use a membership plugin - that's what they are for.  Then, when someone needs to be removed from access, you shut off one person without inconveniencing every other user.

Comment: whether everyone has the same password or not (this can easily be sent out in the monthly newsletter), there should be way to do this without a plugin. after all, plugins are just code? and it looks like you write a membership plugin? how do any of us become better developers if we just keep using plugins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to read [this post](http://unserkaiser.com/blog/2014/02/21/wordpress-password-protected-posts-feature-or-security-leak/) about passwords protected posts. In short: Do not use them.

> QUESTION: Will this strategy keep the info private, or am I missing something?

No, it won't. It will even leak info to search engines and index those.

What you *can* do is to just require the actual *user login* in your template:

```
// @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_login_form/
    wp_login_form();

    // "outer template"
    wp_footer(); # etc.
    return;
}
// Other template code
```